# Where can I find historical data on home equity loan rates?

Tags: united-states, interest-rate, online-data-source, home-equity

I have found a graph of historical **home equity loan** rates on [bankrate.com](http://www.bankrate.com/funnel/graph/default.aspx?cat=8&ids=239,662&state=zz&d=1095&t=MSLine&eco=-1), but I am looking for the underlying data, so I can do a 3-year average.

I found the equivalent for [mortgage rates on Freddie Mac](http://www.freddiemac.com/pmms/pmms30.htm), but I'm specifically looking for home equity loan or HELOC rates.

Comment: Do you have access to data vendor like Bloomberg or Reuters?

Comment: @chrisaycock No, unfortunately I do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HELOCs are often priced as Prime +/- 1/2% or so. There's not one "HELOC" rate, the banks will vary between them, and the rate will also change based on customer FICO score and loan to value. The [Prime Rate](http://www.fedprimerate.com/wall_street_journal_prime_rate_history.htm) can easily be found by searching. Today, it's 3.25%. If you search for today's HELOC rate you'll see a range of 3-5%. For a single number "average," I'd use .5% as an adder to prime.

Comment: This is a good answer for HELOC rates. Any insight into home equity loan rates?